# Petrinet: Decoration and XShift not aligned in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

When a new `begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=2cm]` is used, it creates the TikZ picture 2 cm to the right of existing TikZ picture (X shift).

But, somehow that doesn't seem to work here and the decoration (snake line) is also  not aligned properly.

I was expecting the following:

[image]

But I get this:

[image]

**Note**: I have used the same code in the first TikZ picture hence the right box also has the same diagram. I will change that later.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width  = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{circlenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [>=stealth']
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {r1};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {r2};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {r3};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {r4};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {s2};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {s3}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {s4};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R1) {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=5cm]
  [>=stealth']
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {r1};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {r2};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {r3};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {r4};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {s2};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {s3}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {s4};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R2) {};
  \end{scope}
    \draw [thick,decorate,
decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,
pre=moveto,pre length=1mm,post length=2mm}]
(R1) -- (R2) node [above=1mm,midway,text width=3cm,align=center]
{replacement of the \textcolor{red}{capacity} by \textcolor{red}{two places}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `xshift` never shifts the picture unless you work with overlay pictures and absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Moving with `xshift`, `yshift` or `shift` only works within a single `tikzpicture` environment.

Here, you have **two** tikzpicture environments, so it has **no** effect.

It is enough to include the figure in a `scope` environment to be able to move it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width  = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{circlenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [>=stealth']
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {r1};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {r2};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {r3};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {r4};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {s2};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {s3}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {s4};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R1) {};
  \end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
  [>=stealth']
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {r1};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {r2};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {r3};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {r4};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {s2};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {s3}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {s4};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R2) {};
  \end{scope}
    \draw [thick,decorate,
decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,
pre=moveto,pre length=1mm,post length=2mm}]
(R1) -- (R2) node [above=1mm,midway,text width=3cm,align=center]
{replacement of the \textcolor{red}{capacity} by \textcolor{red}{two places}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, `xshift` never shifts the picture unless you work with overlay pictures and absolute positioning. And you do not need `fit` here, it is easier to do that just with `local bounding box`. You can shift these local bounding boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width  = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{circlenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {r1};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {r2};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {r3};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {r4};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {s2};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {s3}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {s4};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to[out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to[out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to[out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to[bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to[out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to[out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to[bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to[bend left=45] (r3);
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[gray!15,rounded corners] (L.south west) rectangle (L.north east);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=8.5cm,local bounding box=R]
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {r1};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {r2};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {r3};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {r4};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {s2};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {s3}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {s4};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[gray!15,rounded corners] (R.south west) rectangle (R.north east);
\end{scope}
\draw [thick,decorate,
decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,
pre=moveto,pre length=1mm,post length=2mm}]
(L) -- (R) node [above=1mm,midway,text width=3cm,align=center]
{replacement of the \textcolor{red}{capacity} by \textcolor{red}{two places}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is the tutorial `A Petri-Net for Hagen` in the Tikz manual that uses the `fit` library.

Comment: @AndréC The point of answers is to go beyond what already existed before.